# php uniqid() behaviour in session Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, zend-framework2, sessionid

I am using sessions to store some informations about my images like this.

```
            $imageId = uniqid();
            $imageName = $tempName;
            $viewImages[] = array(
                    'name' => $this->getDressImageUrl($tempName) . "?sid=" . time(),
                    'image' => $imageId,
                    'main_image' => $imgData['main_image']
            );
                    print_r($imageId);
                    $this->saveImageNameToSession($imageId, $imageName, 'test');
```

Function saveImageNameToSession looks like this.

```
protected function saveImageNameToSession($imageId, $imageName, $text) {
    print_r($imageId);

    $sessionRegistry = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('session_registry');
    $images = $sessionRegistry->offsetGet($this->getSessionKey('imgs'));

    $images[$imageId]['image'] = $imageId;
    $images[$imageId]['name'] = $imageName;
    $images[$imageId]['text'] = $text;

    $sessionRegistry->offsetSet($this->getSessionKey('imgs'), $images);
}
```

When i save the info in session a get this array

```
Array
    (
        [52de84947c4de] => Array
            (
                [image] => 52de84947c4de
                [name] => vencanica-vencanica-1-large-a52de23cbaf45f.jpg
                [text] => test
            )


        [52de84947c7f9] => Array
            (
                [image] => 52de84947c7f9
                [name] => vencanica-vencanica-1-large-a52de7349674f2.jpg
                [text] => test
            )

)
```

values 52de84947c4de and 52de84947c7f9 matches with values created with uniqid(), but this is only in Firefox. In Chrome i get different values that do not match with passed uniqid(). I have busted my head with this and can not figure out why this works well in Firefox and doesnt work well in Chrome. What could be the problem?

**Edit:**

If i add the `time()` on `uniqid()` like this `$imageId = uniqid() . time()` in firefox, the values for `imageId` and `image` in session are the same (52de8e69a94611390317161), but if is try it in Chrome `imageId` and `name` in session do not match (52de8ee79242a1390317287 vs 52de8eea5f37a1390317290) notice the last two digits, as if it is created in another time.

Comment: PHP is serverside so it shouldn't be a browser related issue. What is the output of `var_dump` / `print_r` in Chrome?

Comment: i know, that is why i find this very vierd. When i print a session it gives me array like this one, only with different values for image, baseod on uniqid(). If i add the time() on uniqid() like this $imageId = uniqid() . time() in firefox, the values for imageId and image in session are the same (52de8e69a94611390317161), but if is try it in Chrome imageId and name in session do not match (52de8ee79242a1390317287 vs 52de8eea5f37a1390317290) notice the last two digits, as if it is created in another time.

Comment: What is the service `session_registry`?  Is this a php class that you've created?  If so what is the code for the `offsetGet` and `offsetSet` functions?

Comment: That is from Zend framework, you can see it on this link http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.1/classes/Zend.Session.Storage.SessionArrayStorage.PhpReferenceCompatibility.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems was in SeoQuake Extension in Google Chrome. Once i've uninstaled it everything was working great. Do not know why, but uninstaling it got my problem fixed.